# Is there a way to access/dereference and find value of element stored in a vector of double pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, dereference

Basically I have two vectors, one of type  (calling it outer) containing elements which point to another vector whose elements are of type  (henceforth called inner) and the pointers stored as elements in inner point to int type arrays.

I wanted to access the elements of the arrays stored. How do I go about it?

Comment: Please don't describe code, post it. Show the definitions of the vectors in question, and what you want to access.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post a code snippet that shows your attempt to access the elements of your containers. This will help us help you.

Comment: I have rolled back an edit another user made, as I feel it changed the meaning of the question by adding information that was nowhere in the original. It also didn't really make sense, IMHO.

Comment: To begin with, having vectors of double pointers in a C++ program is very fishy. Your overall approach looks wrong. But anyway, your question is too unclear without any code. Please [edit] your question and add some relevant code. Read this: [ask]

Comment: Pointers to vector elements are very fragile - they become invalid if the underlying storage is reallocated. Consider storing indices instead of pointers.

Comment: @molbdnilo can you explain your edit? Why do you think the types are necessarily `int**` and `int*` ?

Comment: @BrennanVincent I read too fast and didn't scroll all the way to the original post.

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
const int num = 2;
int arr[num];
arr[0] = 123;
arr[1] = 456;

vector<int*> inner;
vector<int**> outer;

inner.reserve(num);
outer.reserve(num);

for(int i = 0; i < num; ++i)
{
    inner.push_back(&arr[i]);
    outer.push_back(&inner[i]);
}

cout << "before:";
for (int i : arr) {
    cout << i << " ";
}
cout << endl;

for(int i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
    **(outer[i]) *= 2;
}

cout << "after:";
for (int i : arr) {
    cout << i << " ";
}
cout << endl;
```

Output:

```
before:123 456 
after:246 912
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/AO7xAh)